# How to extend the Ubuntu VPS storage via command line (Without GParted)

Tags: vmware-esxi, partition, ubuntu-18.04, snapshot

I loaded the VPS sever with 50GB snapshot VM image, so now the remaining size of the actual storage of this server is not allocated correctly which is remaining 110GB. The total size of the VPS is 160GB. I tried the following but it's not working as expected.

Attempt 1:
resize2fs /dev/vda3

Error:

[image]

Attempt 2: cfdisk

Error:  **Maximum size is 52611235328 bytes.**

[image]

How can I allocate remaining free space to the /dev/vda3 without losing the data of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 3rd screenshot, I see that LVM is used. So you need lvm commands to resize:

`sudo lvextend -r -l 100%VG vg-ubuntu/lv`

Thanks to `-r` no `resize2fs` is needed afterwards.

A consideration: I'm not sure if `vg-ubuntu/lv` is the name of your logical volume, that's what I could see from the screenshot. In order to give you a better answer, send the results of `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` commands please. In text would be better, no needed for screenshot if possible.

---

According to your results of `vgs` & `lvs` the command should be:
`sudo lvextend -r -l 100%VG ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's the result that you requested. pvs = /dev/vda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <49.00g <24.50g , vgs = ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <49.00g <24.50g . lvs = = ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 24.50g

Comment: Also above command, give me following error, `Volume group "vg-ubuntu" not found
  Cannot process volume group vg-ubuntu`

Comment: I added the new command in my answer, you can try it.